# Network sites search

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

When editing your developer story, you can choose to display SE sites under you profile.

This box gives bad user experience when you have a large number of SE accounts, because the scrollbar is small, so its very sesentive, and the place where its placed is small.

[image]

Can this box get a search option?

Comment: I do agree it's kind of hard to use when you have a lot of sites, we'll work on it and come up with a new UX! It should be super easy to find what you want here.

Comment: Are we sub-optimizing for spam-figthters?

Comment: It would be nice to have a textbox which filters the list, like in the top bar site switcher dropdown (@Stéphane )

Comment: It looks like more than just a few spam fighters have [a substantial amount of sites](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471396#graph). I stand corrected.